# ORA-01843: NOT A VALID MONTH

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, etl

Estoy realizando una ETL y tengo el campo `F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA` tipo `VARCHAR` en origen con los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que en mi tabla destino el campo debe estar en formato `DATE`. Por esta razón, he realizado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA,1,10),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'01/01/1500') FROM TABLA
```

En esta sentencia hago lo siguiente:

1. `SUBSTR` -> Me quedo con los primeros 10 dígitos, es decir, con la fecha DD/MM/YYYY
2. `TO_DATE` -> Convierto el campo a DATE con el formato DD/MM/YYYY
3. `NVL` -> En caso de que no encuentre valor que escriba '01/01/1500'

Por alguna razón, esta sentencia funciona cuando la ejecuto en `Oracle SQL Developer` (ver imagen inferior) pero cuando la ejecuto en `Oracle Data Integrator`, obtengo el error `'Invalid month'`. Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He consultado los parámetros NLS. Adjunta la imagen debajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. En lugar de editar tu pregunta para mostrar la solución, escríbela como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Por cierto, tenés aún varias preguntas en donde ya has encontrado la respuesta, pero no las redactaste como tal. Recordá que, bajo ciertos criterios, [el usuario Comunidad relanza las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1651).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error depende de la configuración por omisión que tenga la sesión del "Oracle Data Integrator".
Como está escrita la sentencia si la columna F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA no tiene dato se tiene un string que dice '01/01/1500' el cual Oracle tratará automáticamente de convertir a un valor de tipo DATE usando la configuración default que tenga la sesión del "Oracle Data Integrator".

Debe es mover la función NVL al interior de la función TO_DATE así:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(NVL(SUBSTR(F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA,1,10),'01/01/1500'),'DD/MM/YYYY') AS SALIDA FROM TABLA
```

Opino que si no tiene valor F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA el valor en la tabla destino debiera también ser nulo.

¿Lo otro es porqué descartar el componente de tiempo?
Para incluirlo sería así:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(NVL(TRIM(:F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA),'01/01/1500 00:00:00'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS FECHA_SALIDA
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la máscara `dd/mm/RRRR` de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Comment: Probando la máscara recomendada, no ha funcionado. NVL(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(F_PET_DATOS_ULTIMA,1,10),'DD-MM-RRRR'),'01/01/1500')

Comment: @Panri93 Perdón, edité la máscara. Para futuras oportunidades, por favor indica algo más descriptivo que "no funciona". Puedes ir y editar la pregunta y **añadir** la salida de probar lo que te indican en respuestas y comentarios

Comment: Ya encontré el error.. Ahora pongo la solución.